# Sidekiq - Accessing stored messages ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm new to Sidekiq and RoR. Scheduled newsletters are stored in Sidekiq until they're posted. The task is that a notification the scheduled details of the newsletter (subject, scheduled at, created at) should be displayed in the form. How do I break it down even further only wanting the specific details? Each scheduled newsletter happens to be a really long string in an array.

```
$r = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new

$r.map {|re| re.args[0]}

output:
$ ["---\n- !ruby/class 'Subscriber'\n- :send_in_batch_now!\n- - 
!ruby/hash:NewsletterOption\n    welcome_message: ''\n    
body_message: ''\n    sender_id: 1\n    sender_name: 8Share Malaysia\n    
from_email: malaysia@8share.com\n    country_code: my\n    test: 
false\n    subject: jkhkjh\n    campaign_ids:\n    - '3'\n    
scheduled: true\n    scheduled_at: 2015-05-28 08:45:00.000000000 Z\n    
errors: []\n    category: version2/d/my/2015/05/26/jkhkjh\n"]
```

Many thanks folks!

Comment: It's yaml, parse and display what you want?

Comment: You mean to say, the newsletter is stored in Sidekiq as yaml ?